# Web page rendering incorrectly on mobile Safari and mobile Chrome

Tags: iphone, html, ios, mobile, safari

I wanted to see if anyone else had ever had an issue with Mobile Safari or Chrome causing web pages to suddenly spit out a ton of garbage.

The issue occurs when I visit the site & refresh multiple times. Suddenly, none of the content renders correctly, but instead looks more like the type of glyphs you'd see in Microsoft Word.

Has anyone ever seen this before and, if so, how did you resolve the problem?

Comment: Check your HTML page's character set. Make sure it is UTF-8

Comment: The default charset is ISO-8859-1. Still, I did determine that when the site was created, they didn't specify a charset or a doctype.

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy I'd like to award this bounty to you - would you please post an answer? You're comment put me on the right path to resolving this problem and I'd like to see you rewarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the character set of the HTML page. Bases on your language or the special characters used in the page, you should use the apt charset. You can learn more about charsets here

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it on iPhone and Android.  On iPhone I suspect its due to the interruption during the page load (getting kCFURLErrorCancelled on the didFailLoadWithError method). Though I am still looking to confirm this issue and still looking for a solution ...

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to tell anything from what you have posted. You should check the meta tags of your page. I would suggest you validate the html source and css of the page [**here**](http://validator.w3.org/) .